# xna - why cant i see the bitmap class while adding photos through photoChooser

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I am trying to add photos to my game through photochooser.
I am using all the right usings (images, shell, etc.) but can't get to the bitmap class
What am I missing?

#### Update:

I tried using System.Windows.Media.Imaging.
and still can't find the bitmapimage class.
I can't find using System.Windows.dll.
can you be more specific?  I get a sgwigly line below bitmapImage.

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult result)

        {
           if (result.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
            {
                var bitmapImage=new 
                System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp =
             new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                bmp.SetSource(result.ChosenPhoto);

            }         
        }
```

Comment: There is no Bitmap class in XNA. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use `System.Bitmap` then this isn't supported on the phone.

You probably want `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage` (in System.Windows.dll) instead.